# Is it possible for the link in search results to open the page in a specific state - e.g. with accordion open or with modal open?

Tags: search, seo, modal-dialog, accordion

I initially asked this in the UX stack, but I'd like Stack Overflow input as well.  I recently found a great [write-up about SEO and anchored links](http://returnonnow.com/2012/01/anchored-links-seo/) .  In particular, I found the following to be very helpful:

> For longer or more complex pages, search engines frequently create
>   direct links to the anchored locations. These are positioned very
>   similarly to sitelinks in function.

Now, here's what I'm trying to figure out... Is it possible for search engines to create direct links to content in an accordion* so that when the link in the results is clicked, it opens the page with the accordion open to the specific reference?  Likewise, is it possible for search engines to create direct links to content in a modal window* so that when the link in the results is clicked, it presents the page with the modal window open with the specific reference?

*Assuming it has been created in a way that is SEO-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines can use HTTP(S) URIs with [fragment identifiers](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.5), theoretically.

So if you have an element with an ID (e.g., `<div id="foobar-1">…</div>`), [anyone](https://superuser.com/a/635774/151741), including search engines, can use an URL (e.g., `http://example.com/page#foobar-1`) to "jump" to this particular element.

It’s irrelevant if this element is part of an accordion or a modal window, as it is essentially only a question of presentation (as long as your preferred presentation "fires" when accessing this fragment).

If or which search engines would show such links on their SERPs is a different question and off-topic for Stack Overflow.